# How to pass a Swift String that just contains white spaces to a C method?

Tags: c, swift, string, libsass

I wrote a Swift wrapper around the C LibSass library and have some trouble with passing a non-empty String to a C method.

The LibSass library provides a method to set a custom indent value. Because this method expects a `const char*` I know that I can just pass my Swift String to this method and Swift will convert it. Because it is the indent, this String just contains white spaces or `\t`, but when I check the value of the getter for the indent, I receive just an empty String. I test this value as follows:

```
XCTAssertEqual( sassOptions.indent, "\t" )
```

Where `sassOptions.indent` returns the indent that should be set.

The indent property is set with `func setIndent(_: String)` that calls the following LibSass method:

```
void sass_option_set_indent(struct Sass_Options* options, const char* indent)
```

The expected `options` argument is stored as an internal property and given to the C method inside the `setIndent(_:String)` Swift function.
I installed the LibSass library with Homebrew (`brew install --HEAD libsass`) and linked the library to my project with [this](https://github.com/robinwalterfit/Swift-libsass) dependency. Everything else is working as I expected.

Does anybody know whether Swift converts a String, that just contains white spaces, to an empty String and how to avoid this behaviour?

My setIndent function:

```
public func setIndent( _ indent: String ) {

        sass_option_set_indent( self.options, indent )

}
```

See also the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/robinwalterfit/Swift-Sass) for the whole code and tests.

Comment: I am not familiar with LibSass, but I am 100% sure that passing the Swift string `"\t"` to a C function taking a  `const char*` argument will not remove the white space.

Comment: @MartinR OK, but I still don't get why the String is empty afterwards... Inside the compiled file there is `@p` used instead of an indent...

Comment: Where is that C library? How do you set the indent?

Comment: @MartinR I updated the question

Comment: Can we see your `setIndent(_:String)` function?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Of course! I will update my question

Comment: You might want to try using the `sass_copy_c_string` function in your setter